# Center overflowing element inside other element

Tags: css

I have an iframe inside a div like this:

```
<section>
   <div>
      <iframe></iframe>
   </div>
</section>
```

the iframe contains a youtube video in flash but that probably won't matter in this case.

I'm building a mosaic and is therfore trying to use the div to crop the iframe to an appropriate size.

this is done by

```
.section
    {height: 251px;
    width: 198px;
    overflow: hidden}
```

Works great but I would like to center the video aswell. For images, I add them as background-images and use

```
background-size: cover
```

to center them. This is neat because they automatically rescale to maximum possible size. However this doesn't work for video. I would settle for simply centering the iframe vertically and horizontally, if possible.

Comment: You want to center the iframe within section?

Comment: or within the DIV, it will have the same effect in practice. as the section and div have the same position.

Comment: Can you make the `iframe` contents a page you control, or must the contents be directly from YouTube?

Answer (score 2):

Will adding this to your css help? It works if div is bigger than section.

```
section div {
    margin-top:-50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvCXm/

Comment: That looks like the right idea, but I don't think `-50%` will always be the right amount. It refers to 50% of the specified parent dimension (e.g. `width: 198px`), so that only centers the iframe if its content is exactly twice as large as the parent (e.g. 396px wide).

Comment: @Rory O'Kane No, idea is that div gets width/height of content that is inside it. So 50% means half of content. Not given exact dimensions it is difficult to exactly center the content.

Answer (score 0):

Wrappping the iframe and use `text-align: center;` to align horizontal center

```
div {
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

or

```
iframe { 
margin: 0 auto; 
display: block;
}
```

Comment: wrapping the iframe in what?

Comment: or `iframe{ margin: 0 auto; display: block;}`

Comment: try positioning absolute .  If possible share the link?

Comment: you can't use `text-align: center` on an iframe. I've tried using `display: inline` it just doesn't affect it.

Comment: @pandavenger I'm not assinging text-align for `iframe`, it is for the `div` which makes the content at center inside it.

Comment: @user1671639 that's what i'm trying to say, if the iframe overflow, text-align center won't center it no matter if it's treated as a block or an inline character

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
iframe {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to center block elements:

```css
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: nope, I think it doesn't work because the iframe is overflowing

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. You're right, this won't work as is.